# Cygwin and make - Current directory '.' not found

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I am trying to execute the make command with a Makefile `make build`. I am getting an error in this makefile command:

```
build:
   ./folder/file.exe file.config
```

And I am getting: `The command "." is either misspelled or could not be found.`

The same error when I am trying to execute this:

```
cat: '\': Is a directory
make × ERR  cat         ../../../vendor/js-aruco/src/aruco.js \
```

I have installed Cygwin on Windows 10 and I have defined all environment variables in Path:

- CYGWIN_HOME = C:\cygwin64
- Path = %CYGWIN_HOME%\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\sbin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\sbin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\local\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\local\sbin;C:\MinGW\bin;.;

So Cygwin does not recognize commands like '.' or '\' when I am trying to execute the command 'make'. I have also installed `mingw32-make` but it does not work.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What happens when you try `./folder/file.exe file.config` on the command line?

Comment: It works on the command line. With make it does not.

Comment: What is your `$SHELL` environment variable?  It sounds like for some reason `make` is trying to use the Windows `cmd.exe` as its shell and not a UNIX shell provided by Cygwin.  The error message 'The command "..." is either misspelled or could not be found.' comes from `cmd.exe`, so this is not normal Cygwin behavior.